# Mocking for an instantiated class variable

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following setup:

```py
# main.py

from foo import Foo
from bar import Bar

def main():
  foo = Foo()

  result = Bar.method_1(foo)

  print(result)
```

```py
# bar.py

class Bar:

def method_1(foo):
    return foo.method_2()
```

```py
# foo.py

class Foo:

  def __method():
    return EXTERNAL_CALL

  def method_2():
    return self.__method()
```

(class `Bar` and `method_1` is a little more complicated in reality; I know this current setup seems redundant)

My goal is to create a test for `main()`, but I want to mock out the `EXTERNAL_CALL` via patch.

I have been reading documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) and on where to properly patch, but I must be making a mistake still.

My current thinking is that since `main` is what instantiates the class, I need to do the following:

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from src import main, bar, foo

@mock.patch("main.Foo")
def mock(mock_class):
  mock_class.method_2.return_value = "MOCKED"

class TestModel(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_main():
    main.main()
```

Instead of seeing `MOCKED` printed out, I get an error from the `__method()` being called, and trying to make an external call. Is my patch setup incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The `patch` decorator should decorate your test method itself. So basically just merge your `mock` and `test_main` methods:

```
class TestModel(unittest.TestCase):
  @mock.patch("main.Foo")
  def test_main(self, mock_class):
    mock_class.return_value.method_2.return_value = "MOCKED"
    main.main()
```

If you want the class to be mocked during all of the test methods in your test class, you could define the [`setUp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) method and decorate it instead.

Comment: Trying this, I get error that `main.py` does not have attribute `Foo`.

If it is relevant, technically `from foo import Foo` is done with `main()`.

Comment: Although even making `from foo import Foo` outside `main()` and then implementing your solution, I still does see the mocked value.

Comment: @user43395 looks like it should be `mock_class.return_value.method_2.return_value`. Will update my answer.